# Outlook 2003 as default email client in 64-bit Windows 7 Home Premium

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, microsoft-outlook-2003

I'm trying to help someone configure Outlook 2003 as the default email client in their 64-bit Windows 7 Home Premium installation, but this program never appears in the list of "Default Programs" (pictured below) as an option (in fact, none of the Microsoft Office 2003 programs appear in this list).

I've also tried the "Detect & Repair" option under the Help menu, but this didn't make any difference either.

Is there a known compatibility problem with this scenario?  Searching Google has turned up quite a few anecdotes with people experiencing the same problem -- the suggested solutions of "re-install MS-Office" (already done that) and "use a different email client" (the user specified Outlook as a requirement) don't resolve this in this case.

A Windows Registry hack would be greatly welcomed (I haven't found any for this with Google either).

*Please note:  A closed-source solution that somehow fixes Windows is not an acceptable solution because of the potential spyware factor, unless that solution is provided by Microsoft.*

[image: A screenshot of the "Set Default Programs" window in Windows 7 displaying many programs (including other mail clients), but lacking Outlook.]

Comment: Did you find and/or try "OL2003fix.exe" yet?

Comment: @techie007:  Thanks!  That doesn't come from Microsoft, nor does it appear to be open source or seem to have any documentation.  Since the target computer is used in a business, I can't take the risk that it might contain SpyWare.  Do you know if the source code and/or documentation for this product is available?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the alternative way? Configuring in Outlook itself? You can do that in Tools -> Options -> other. Check this for details: http://www.technlg.net/windows/set-default-email-application/

[image]

Comment: I don't remember seeing this option in OutLook 2003.  I'll take a look on Monday (and if it solves the problem, I'll mark this as the Accepted answer; for now, +1 at least because it shows a possible solution that I think should work).

Comment: This option does exist, but it doesn't appear to do anything. Outlook still doesn't show up in the list of Default Programs